# Extreme Video stretching in the VSE

Tags: video-sequence-editor, video, audio

I rendered a 10 second animation with 230 frames, but when I uploaded it into the video sequence editor in the exact same blend file it got stretched to 6 minutes making it off sync with the music.
[image: audio on the bottom strip and video on the top strip]

As you can see the video is massive compared to the audio strip

I think I have to adjust the frame rate (which I do not know how), but shouldn't the lengths be the same since it's made in the same blend file?

Comment: Did you render it as a .mkv in an older version of Blender? I seem to recall that some Matroska exports were broken but are good in recent builds. Try exporting again if you can with an alternate codec. You really should render as frame sequences before delivery anyway ;-)

Answer (score 0):

you can either add an Effect Strip/Speed Control or re-encode the video

```
ffmpeg -i yourfile.mkv -c:v libx264 -crf 23 -pix_fmt yuv420p -c:a copy -r 24 newfile.mkv
```

Or try matching the frames per second in the Blender Render settings before you add the video in VSE.

I always use the ffmpeg command as matter of course.

Hopefully Blender 2.8 will have a new ffmpeg library and this will go away.